# What repository needs to be enabled for Sun Studio 12.5?

Tags: solaris, sunstudio

We are part of the Oracle OTN Network. Oracle Solaris Studio publisher is installed (enabled?) and allows us to support up to Sun Studio 12.4. We want to add support for Sun Studio 12.5 for the next release.

We tried to install [Sun Studio 12.5 following the 12.4 instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37072/gozsz.html), but we are not finding it:

```
$ pkg list -af 'pkg://solarisstudio/developer/solarisstudio-125/*'
pkg list: no packages matching 'pkg://solarisstudio/developer/solarisstudio-125/*' known
$ pkg search solarisstudio | grep 125
$
```

Which package repository can we find Sun Studio 12.5?

---

Here's an expected result and the result of searching for the latest component.

```
$ pkg search '*c++@12.4*'
INDEX      ACTION VALUE                                             PACKAGE
require    depend developer/solarisstudio-124/c++@12.4,5.11-1.0.0.0 pkg:/developer/solarisstudio-124@12.4-1.0.0.0
$ pkg search '*c++@12.5*'
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see which versions of Studio have been released at this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html

12.5 is in beta release, but it has not been released yet.

I believe it will be available in the same repo as 12.4 when it finally ships.

Additions:

The beta release is available as java-based standalone installers for Linux and Solaris 10.  It's available as a tarball for Solaris 11.  There are no IPS packages for Solaris 11 for the beta release of Studio.  The IPS packages will be available at the official release of 12.5

Comment: Thanks Chris. I knew Sun Studio 12.5 was in beta; that's why I went looking for it (stating it for completeness). So I am clear...  Solaris does not provide a Debian equivalent to "Testing repo", which is where I would expect to find Sun Studio 12.5. (I'm trying to avoid the manual install because I have to do the manual cleanup, and I have to solve the errors I encounter on my own).

Comment: Thanks again Chris. Related, is the CC compiler located at `/opt/solarisstudio12.5/bin/CC`? I ask because our [test suite](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh) assumes so based on 12.3 and 12.4, but I have not been able to actually verify it. (I can ask another question so you can get more points, if desired).

Comment: I think the path will change in 12.5 (more than just the number), so you'll need to use different paths for the different releases.  The bin/CC part will be the same, but the first part will change.

Comment: You were right about name, path and version string changes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears Sun Studio 12.5 was released for Solaris 11. Also see [Download Options for Oracle Developer Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/index-jsp-141149.html). It can be added from the commad line with:

```
sudo pkg install  --accept developerstudio-125
```

Once installed, CC is located at:

```
$ ls /opt/developerstudio12.5/bin/
analyzer              er_cp                 perftools_validate
bcheck                er_export             perftools_whichami
binopt                er_generic            ptclean
c++filt               er_html               ripc
c89                   er_html_cols          rtc_patch_area
c99                   er_html_columnsD      rxm
cb                    er_html_columnsI      rxs
cc                    er_kernel             smctl
CC                    er_label              solstudio
...
```

The compiler is awful, though. It crashes when testing Debug, Release, C++03, C++11, C++17, with inline ASM, without inline ASM, etc. The bad thing is/was, they are different crashes and not repeats of the same crash. Also see [Developer Studio 12.5 and Static error checker encountered an unexpected error](https://community.oracle.com/message/13921822) on the Oracle boards.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler supports C++11 and partial C++14 not c++17.