# How do I install cairocffi in solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, cairo

I saw xcffib is a prerequisite so I tried to install it with:

```
~# pip install xcffib
```

But I got [this error message](http://pastebin.com/riRVumsd)  and I don't understand what 'cc' is, I installed gcc.

**Update:**

I tried to export the location of my libffi-dev headers

```
#echo $LIBFFI_LIBS 
-L/opt/csw/lib -lffi
#echo $LIBFFI_CFLAGS
-I/opt/csw/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include
```

And runing

```
CC="gcc -std=gnu99" pip install xcffib
```

or

```
CC="gcc -std=gnu99" pip install cffi
```

still doesn't find the header: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or director

Comment: I would try `CC="gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/csw/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include"`

Comment: The output of that command is here http://pastebin.com/asFF93gM

Comment: Looks like `pip` insist using the Studio compiler (`cc`) and not the Gnu one (`gcc`). This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833267/what-repository-needs-to-be-enabled-for-sun-studio-12-5

Comment: I installed the studio compiler 12.4 and it worked, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update, converting my comment to an answer to help future people having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `pip` and/or `cairocffi` are expecting the Oracle Studio compiler to be installed.

[Installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833267/what-repository-needs-to-be-enabled-for-sun-studio-12-5) fixes the issue you are having.